# Pandas Column values between range like 1-250, 251-500, so on

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Dataset:**

```
    id    MarketPlaceValuation
    0     100
    1     250
    2     200
    3     100
    4     325
    5     175
    6     150
    7     125
    8     225
    9     325
    10    625
    11    100
    12     75
    13    100
    14    200
    15    225
    ..     ..
    40    425
    41    100
    42    275
    43    200
    44    250
    45    500
    46    225
    47    400
    48     75
    49    200
```

and so on.
Where **MarketPlaceValuation** Values are between 1-100000.

**Sample Output Should be:**

```
Valuation Segment
1-250
251-500
501-1000
1001-1500
1501-2000
2001-3000
3001-4000
4001-5000
5001-100000
```

**I tried following:**

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['MarketPlaceValuation'], np.arange(0,501,250))).count()
```

But not getting proper output.

Next, I want to get an average of other columns as per this column range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
#specify bins
bins = [0,250,500,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000,5000,100000]
#generate labels from bins
labels = ['{} - {}'.format(i + 1, j) for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 

cat = pd.cut(df['MarketPlaceValuation'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
#get mean per categories
df = df.groupby(cat)['MarketPlaceValuation'].mean()
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, is there any other options than this? output looks like `(250, 500]` and I want to save this columns in another csv file

Comment: And need `1-250`, `251-500`?

Comment: What are these other values with these:  `1-250          9311
251-500        3144`

Comment: This is count per groups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159978/discussion-between-rathod-and-jezrael).